# Issue with facet.wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, fill, facet-wrap

I try to make the same plot as the following one but for several individuals.

[image]


The code for the following plot is:

```
ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))
values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = c(3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.15, 3.5)
)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3,
        0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
  y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5,
        2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2)
)

# Currently we need to manually merge the two together
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))

p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = id))
```

I have a data.frame which contains the coordinates of the polygon named position.

To do this on several individuals at the same time I store the intensity values of each polygon in a new data.frame (data) which contains the individual identifier (MID) the intensity value (value) and polygon identifier (ID).

However when I use facet.wrap I don't know what to put in the geom_polygon function so that the background is the intensities values stored in the data object.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
data <- data.frame(MID = c(rep("1",6), rep("2",6)), value = rnorm(12), ID = c(1:6,1:6))
rnorm(12)
###
p <- ggplot(data) +
  facet_wrap(~MID, ncol = 7) +
  geom_polygon(data = positions, aes(x = x, y = y, group = id), colour = "black")+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill= "white"),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 6)
  )
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Merging positions with values is the way to go, but you should use the same `id`s, so that the merge works:

```
data <- data.frame(MID = c(rep("1",6), rep("2",6)), value = rnorm(12), id = rep(ids,2))
datapoly <- merge(data, positions, by = c("id"))

p <- ggplot(datapoly,aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  facet_wrap(~MID, ncol = 7) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group = id), colour = "black")+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill= "white"),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 6)
  )
p
```

[image]